# new release of ERC1155SupplyUpgradeale has compilation issues

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin-contracts, erc-1155

The new contracts lib from OZ, specifically [ERC1155UspplyUpgradeable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/ERC1155SupplyUpgradeable.sol)
has compilation issues before even inheriting it in any child contract (check screenshot below) any idea why? or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same compilation error in `update` function in any of ERC1155Upgradeable if using Remix you have to delete OZ from `npm` directory and re-compile your contract. the error is a conflict from Remix and if you're using any other framework, uninstall and re-install new OZ contracts.

error is due to changes in OZ inheritance mechanism as the new library doesn't include libraries and interfaces, that's why they're imported from @openzeppelin in the new lib. while other inheritance is relative.